# Google drive service account

Tags: authentication, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I have used service account to manipulate spreadsheet files of all users under same domain.
Now I want to use service account to fetch any user's data.
Can i use service account to read other user's drive data if user is not from my own g-suite domain?

Comment: No - and I hope you'd *expect* not to be able to. If you want to get access to my files, and I've got nothing to do with you, you'll have to ask my permission via an OAuth2 prompt.

Answer (score 0):

That is absolutely not possible due to privacy and security concerns.

If you want to obtain data from a user which is not part of your domain, that user will have to authenticate to your application by manually completing the OAuth flow.

You may read more at:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)